# Simulated annealing in R

Tags: r

I am new in R and I have to implement simulated annealing for schaffer function and I did it. However I am not sure about the correctness of the code.

```
simulated_annealing <- function(schaffer, step, s0, niter) {
s_n <- s0
iter_count <- 0
for (k in 1:niter) {     
    T <- (1 - step)^k
    s_new <- rnorm(2, s_n, 1)
    dif <- func(s_new) - func(s_n)
    if (dif < 0) {
        s_n = s_new 
    } else {
        random <- runif(1,0,1)
        if (random < exp(-dif/T)) {
            s_n <- s_new
        }
    }
    iter_count <- iter_count + 1

    print(sprintf("The number of iteration was: %f",iter_count))
    print(sprintf("Function at s_new: %f", func(s_new)))
    print(sprintf("Function at s_n: %f", func(s_n)))
    print(sprintf("Current point: %f", s_n))
    print(sprintf("Temperature: %f", T))
}
return(s_n)
}



schaffer <- function(xx)
{x1 <- xx[1]
x2 <- xx[2]
fact1 <- (sin(x1^2-x2^2))^2 - 0.5
fact2 <- (1 + 0.001*(x1^2+x2^2))^2
y <- 0.5 + fact1/fact2
return(y)
}
```

It is how the simulated annealing works:

```
simulated_annealing(schaffer,0.1,c(0,2),10)
```

Output:

```
[1] "The number of iteration was: 1.000000"
[1] "Function at s_new: 0.899459"
[1] "Function at s_n: 0.572171"
[1] "Current point: 0.000000" "Current point: 2.000000"
[1] "Temperature: 0.900000"
[1] "The number of iteration was: 2.000000"
[1] "Function at s_new: 0.047084"
[1] "Function at s_n: 0.047084"
[1] "Current point: 1.022082" "Current point: 2.095950"
[1] "Temperature: 0.810000"
[1] "The number of iteration was: 3.000000"
[1] "Function at s_new: 0.153559"
[1] "Function at s_n: 0.047084"
[1] "Current point: 1.022082" "Current point: 2.095950"
[1] "Temperature: 0.729000"
[1] "The number of iteration was: 4.000000"
[1] "Function at s_new: 0.359053"
[1] "Function at s_n: 0.047084"
[1] "Current point: 1.022082" "Current point: 2.095950"
[1] "Temperature: 0.656100"
[1] "The number of iteration was: 5.000000"
[1] "Function at s_new: 0.828496"
[1] "Function at s_n: 0.047084"
[1] "Current point: 1.022082" "Current point: 2.095950"
[1] "Temperature: 0.590490"
[1] "The number of iteration was: 6.000000"
[1] "Function at s_new: 0.075788"
[1] "Function at s_n: 0.075788"
[1] "Current point: 0.344227" "Current point: 0.629732"
[1] "Temperature: 0.531441"
[1] "The number of iteration was: 7.000000"
[1] "Function at s_new: 0.713948"
[1] "Function at s_n: 0.075788"
[1] "Current point: 0.344227" "Current point: 0.629732"
[1] "Temperature: 0.478297"
[1] "The number of iteration was: 8.000000"
[1] "Function at s_new: 0.000717"
[1] "Function at s_n: 0.000717"
[1] "Current point: -0.106265" "Current point: -0.192747"
[1] "Temperature: 0.430467"
[1] "The number of iteration was: 9.000000"
[1] "Function at s_new: 0.844424"
[1] "Function at s_n: 0.000717"
[1] "Current point: -0.106265" "Current point: -0.192747"
[1] "Temperature: 0.387420"
[1] "The number of iteration was: 10.000000"
[1] "Function at s_new: 0.993481"
[1] "Function at s_n: 0.000717"
[1] "Current point: -0.106265" "Current point: -0.192747"
[1] "Temperature: 0.348678"
[1] -0.1062647 -0.1927468
```

I do not know if it works well and how to estimate the best point - every time it seems that it is the point of last iteration

Comment: Hi, could you give an use example of this function?

Comment: It is one of the method to optimize the global minimum of schaffer function

Comment: So, could you give a code example with outputs?

Comment: I would like to have the same output as here http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/examples/simulated-annealing-options.html in reproducing results

Comment: Ok. Lets see what your function is doing then. What about edit your question and demonstrate your function in action?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how I would rewrite your code, comments to follow.

```
simulated_annealing <- function(func, s0, niter = 10, step = 0.1) {

   # Initialize
   ## s stands for state
   ## f stands for function value
   ## b stands for best
   ## c stands for current
   ## n stands for neighbor
   s_b <- s_c <- s_n <- s0
   f_b <- f_c <- f_n <- func(s_n)
   message("It\tBest\tCurrent\tNeigh\tTemp")
   message(sprintf("%i\t%.4f\t%.4f\t%.4f\t%.4f", 0L, f_b, f_c, f_n, 1))

   for (k in 1:niter) {     
      Temp <- (1 - step)^k
      # consider a random neighbor
      s_n <- rnorm(2, s_c, 1)
      f_n <- func(s_n)
      # update current state
      if (f_n < f_c || runif(1, 0, 1) < exp(-(f_n - f_c) / Temp)) {
         s_c <- s_n
         f_c <- f_n
      }
      # update best state
      if (f_n < f_b) {
         s_b <- s_n
         f_b <- f_n         
      }
      message(sprintf("%i\t%.4f\t%.4f\t%.4f\t%.4f", k, f_b, f_c, f_n, Temp))
   }
   return(list(iterations = niter, best_value = f_b, best_state = s_b))
}

sol <- simulated_annealing(schaffer, s0 = c(0, 2))
#  It   Best    Current Neigh   Temp
#  0    0.5722  0.5722  0.5722  1.0000
#  1    0.1054  0.1054  0.1054  0.9000
#  2    0.1054  0.1922  0.1922  0.8100
#  3    0.1054  0.1922  0.3579  0.7290
#  4    0.1054  0.1922  0.9059  0.6561
#  5    0.1054  0.6428  0.6428  0.5905
#  6    0.1054  0.8893  0.8893  0.5314
#  7    0.1054  0.1597  0.1597  0.4783
#  8    0.1054  0.6489  0.6489  0.4305
#  9    0.1054  0.7535  0.7535  0.3874
#  10   0.1054  0.2236  0.2236  0.3487

sol
# $iterations
# [1] 10
#
# $best_value
# [1] 0.1053682
# 
# $best_state
# [1] -0.3203791  1.7080835
```

Now the comments, in no particular order:

1. when defining your function, you meant to name the first argument  `func`, not `schaffer`. That was a bug.
2. `niter` and `steps` are the kind of arguments that could use an optional value so I made it so. And once an argument has an optional value, it is recommended to move it to the end of the argument list, hence `function(func, s0, niter = 50, step = 0.1)`.
3. I renamed `T` to `Temp` for 1) it is more descriptive and more likely to suggest that this is the annealing's temperature variable, but mostly 2) R provides `T` as a shortcut for `TRUE`, although you can overwrite it like you just did here. This is a horrible feature of the R language and you should avoid using `T` both for `TRUE` or as your own variable.
4. `message` is probably a more appropriate tool for logging. I also transformed the code so it prints one row per iteration. I hope you'll agree the log is much easier to look at this way.
5. Keeping track of the best state is an improvement over the "vanilla" version simulated annealing process which only reports the current state at the last iteration. If you want it that way, then you need to use three states: best, current, neighbor. Which I implemented here.
6. In addition to keeping track of the current state and best state, it is recommended to keep track of their function values, so you do not have to make unnecessary function calls to re-compute them at each iteration.
7. Like the matlab function you referred to, it is preferable to return a list so you can provide more outputs than just the best state.
8. Always, it is important to comment your code to make it easier to understand and maintain.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to the best practises in R coding ya should not write "return" at the end of the function. You should omit this word. So it should be:

`y`
not `return(y)`

Comment: I would not agree, please see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738823/explicitly-calling-return-in-a-function-or-not. Which "best practices" are you referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to documents of Hadley Wickham. He had written to not to use return when it is not necessery. But I can't find it now... Maybe he had deleted this...